I just wanted to know if there is a possibility that in solidity we can have array of string?
I have specific Requirements for a project, where i have to store multiple strings against one owner in a mapping but i noticed there is no string arrays in solidity
Is there an alternative way of doing it?

Please head here to get your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716858/string-array-in-solidity

You can definitely achieve that using mappings to dynamic arrays. You can map an address or any other identifier to a dynamic array of strings, by defining a mapping variable like:
mapping(address => string[]) stringMap;

Here’s an example contract for the same:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract StringStorage {
    mapping(address => string[]) stringMap;

    function addString(address owner, string memory newString) public {
        stringMap[owner].push(newString);
    }

    function getStrings(address owner) public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return stringMap[owner];
    }
}

This basic contract allows you to store multiple strings for each address and retrieve them as needed.
So,  if you call the addString()function by passing the corresponding arguments of type address and string as:

0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4, hello


0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4, world



Now, when you call the getStrings() function by passing the corresponding address argument as 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4, then it'll return an array of 2 strings as:
string[]: hello,world


